# Do break operators turn while loop conditions from True to False?

Tags: python

Check out this very basic while loop in Python:

```
while True:
    response = input("Say something: ")
    if response == 'bye':
        break
    if response != 'bye':
        continue
```

This script prompts the user for input. If the user would like to say hello (or really just about anything), the loop will continually prompt the user for a new response until the user finally enters: "bye". If the answer is "bye", the loop breaks.

My million dollar question for all of you: For the purpose of while loops in general, is it safe to say that the `break` statement turns a while condition from `True` to `False`, therefore exiting the loop?

I realize that lines 5 and 6 really aren't necessary because even without them the loop would continue to perform as I described above. I added the `continue` statement to demonstrate the distinction between `break` (turning the while condition to False) and 'continue' (allowing the while condition to remain True).

In case I need to refer back to the source or origin of this question, I got this idea from Andrei Neagoie's Udemy course content for "Complete Python Developer in 2019" (Section 4: Lecture 71: "While Loops 2").

Comment: `break` condition does not change while loop condition. It breaks the execution and exits the loop. It will not execute any statements after that. The `continue` statement also breaks the execution but it does that for a particular iteration in which the continue statement is executed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it tries to frame the concept in a way that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, would it be easier if I just deleted my question?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The question makes fine sense to me - and supposing it didn't, shouldn't we ask clarification instead of destroying the question?

Comment: @Drone4four Do not delete it, your question is fine - you've got an unlucky moderator review.

Comment: IMHO this question doesn't make any sense. In the question itself, the OP is saying *I added the continue operator to demonstrate the distinction between break (turning the while condition to False) and 'continue' (allowing the while condition to remain True)*

Comment: @CodeIt OP is _wrong_, but wrong in a clear manner that allows correction. OP's actually taking a step further in Python learning to understand how things work at a lower level - which should be anything but discouraged.

Comment: @Drone4four To add to your knowledge, `break` and `continue` statements are there is all of the popular programming languages. If you just google *How break statement works* you would see a lot of detailed as well as flow chart based explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` does not alter the values in any variables, but it simply ends the loop.  You can check it out by using another variable to control the loop like this:

```
other_variable = "whatever"
while other_variable == "whatever":
    response = input("Say something: ")
    if response == 'bye':
        break
    if response != 'bye':
        continue 
print(other_variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the way that C language handles `break` and `continue`, Python will jump to outside of the loop escope when it reaches the `break` statement and, when it reaches a `continue` statement, it will jump back to the loop's test expression.